# phpMyAdmin: change bind address of MySQL on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

**How do I change the bind address of a mysql databse through phpmyadmin?**
I am new at this and really dont know what I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You need to edit the configuration file of your MySQLd (usually in `/etc/mysql`).

Comment: How do I access that?

Comment: Well that depends entirely on how you are able to access your server. Usually it's ssh. Then you can use a text editor of your choice.